# How to train the battery

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging

I am trying to find the way to use my battery in the most efficient manner.

I found several suggestions how to achieve the longest life of the battery, and one of these suggestions is quite strange and mysterious. Check it out:

> - Turn on your phone;
> - Connect the charger and wait until the battery is full-charged (green indicator is on);
> - Disconnect the charger;
> - Wait until the green indicator is off and connect the charger back;
> - When green indicator is on, turn off the phone.
>
> Now, continue with **switched off** phone.
>
> 1. Disconnect the charger;
> 2. Wait until the green indicator is off;
> 3. Connect the charger, wait for green indicator and disconnect the charger again;
> 4. Repeat the "3" step 10 times. This might take from 30 seconds to 30 minutes, usual that's about 1 minute.
>
> This procedure takes some time, but it proved to be worth the cost.

The original article is in another language (russian), so it would not be very useful to post it here, but, to be on the safe side, here's [original article](http://www.bdroid.ru/?p=223).

I am pretty unclear about chemical processes going in the battery, so I can't check out what exactly happened during this mysterious actions.

I did not try to do this with my phone because i'm not sure this isn't harmful for the battery. But at least one person confirmed that these actions helped him to enlarge battery life for at least one cycle.

So, the question is: why exactly the battery's lifecycle becomes enlared, and isn't it harmful to battery? Finally, is it good idea to do all this stuff?

Comment: Is this really an Android issue?

Comment: Well, the original article is about battery saving on Android devices. Maybe these steps is acceptible for other devices, i don't know.

Comment: Android doesn't interact with chemical processes, you know. So, it's off-topic here... Voting to close.

Comment: This doesn't do anything for your battery, in fact it could be harmful.  It's just messing with Android's battery stats in an attempt to make it charge longer and shut off later.  I wouldn't expect good results.

Comment: More than the battery, I believe this is one of the ways that the battery gauge (software) is being "calibrated". As in most situations like these - YMMV.

Comment: HTC put out a notice a while back saying this was the best way to fully charge their phones too. i'll see if i can find the article.

Comment: I rephrased this question and asked it on Electronics SE - http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33003/3552

Comment: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_charge_when_to_charge_table

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is called trickle charging. It's basically useless in modern LiON battery as the safety mechanism in the battery should have turned off the charging mechanism when the battery is near full capacity to prevent over charging, because over charging a LiON battery could cause explosion.

Comment: Should be off topic, here's the real expert answers: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33003/is-there-any-sense-in-this-technique-for-charging-li-ion-batteries